# Possible to have the default landing page of my Sharepoint Site be an applicaiton page?

Tags: application-pages, landing-page

So basically when someone goes to:

```
http://mysite.com
```

I would like to show an Application Page that I have created, without the giant URL.  Example of the giant URL :

```
http://mysite.com/_layouts/ap/myAppPage.aspx
```

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is! Go to **http://mysite.com/_Layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx** and change the URL.

Or via the UI:

**Site actions > Site Settings > User Interface > Welcome Page** and change the URL.

---

**Update**

I just tried myself and I see that none of them work. It seems like that the page has to reside in the content database and not just the domain.

I found a workaround though. On your landingpage, you can insert a HTML-Formular webpart in which you can write some javascript which will redirect the user.

Another option is to develop a webpart which automatically redirects to the given application page of your choice.

With either of these 2, you of course can't go to the page and edit it after they are inserted, as they will redirect you ASAP. This can be countered by entering the URL of the set landing page and then add `?contents=1` (*http://mysite.com/pages/default.aspx?contens=1*) which will open a page telling you which webparts are on the page, and through that you can remove them, in case you don't want it to redirect any more.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: When I try to do that I get the error: `The specified welcome page is not valid or does not exist within the current site.`  I have confirmed that I can get to the URL through browser.

Comment: @AbeMiessler How have you entered the URL? Like this: `/_layouts/ap/myAppPage.aspx`? Or like this: `http://mysite.com/_layouts/ap/myAppPage.aspx`?

Comment: The second example.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Looke at my updated answer :)

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in more detail?
I am also trying to do this.I am trying to follow your suggestion of entering a javascript in the landing page.
Please elabrote this. thank you in advance.

Comment: @gurmeet Yes of course. SharePoint doesn't allow you to set application pages in the `_layouts`folder as your landing page. So instead you insert a HTML-form webpart on your existing landing page in which you insert some javascript which will redirect the user when loaded. This javascript can look something like this: `function RedirectUser() { window.location = "http://www.google.com/"; } window.load = RedirectUser();`. Doing this will make the site redirect anyone who now types in `www.MyWebUrl.com` which e.g. has `www.MyWebUrl.com/pages/default.aspx` as landing page.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

1) First create a page to handle the redirection

2) Then create a module to deploy this file

3) Then change the welcome page

All with c# and without publishing sites.

See the complete solution here: [Application page as home page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176517/application-page-as-home-page/176556#176556)

Answer (score -1):

```
$site = Get-SPSite mysite_page
$web = $site.RootWeb
$folder = $web.RootFolder
$folder.WelcomePage = "myAppPage.aspx"
$folder.update()
$web.update()
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```