# Use an application page as the default/welcome page

Tags: application-pages

Is it possible to use an **application page**, residing in the `_layouts` folder, as the default Welcome page of SharePoint?

According to the [`WelcomePage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.welcomepage.aspx) property, only Site Pages can be used as the welcome page. A hack around would be to create a dummy ghostable Site Page, that basically redirects to the application page that I want to display as the welcome page. However, I wanted to avoid this, as I don't really need a Site Page for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, here is an example:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$assignment=Start-SPAssignment
$web=Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://testsite" -AssignmentCollection $assignment
$rootFolder=$web.RootFolder
$rootFolder.WelcomePage= "$rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl _layouts/pages/yourpage.aspx"
$rootFolder.Update()
Stop-SPAssignment $assignment
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
Write-Host ‘Welcome Page Set Successfully…’
Write-Host ‘Press any key to exit…’
$x=$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey(“NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown”)
$Host.SetShouldExit(1)
```

Comment: Hi Falak, I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to change the WelcomePage from default.aspx to the new one, even though the WelcomePage of $rootFolder is set accordingly.

Comment: Also, I'm using a Blank Site, and I do not have the Publishing Feature active. Is it required?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem in the past by setting up a redirection.

Follow the instructions [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/31802/20173) to set up a redirect page. I had to use SharePoint Designer to put my redirect page in the root of the Site.

Or follow [these instructions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/55294/20173) to set up an IIS URL Rewrite rule. In this case I set the Match URL regular expression pattern to `^$`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set Application pages as Welcome Page, only Site pages located either at the root web or from a Pages library.

Please refer to [Possible to have the default landing page of my Sharepoint Site be an applicaiton page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30419/possible-to-have-the-default-landing-page-of-my-sharepoint-site-be-an-applicaito/30420#30420)