# Set an application page as home page in a team site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to set an application page as a home page in a team site sharepoint 2013 it's possible?
I would like to do that in the feature activated event.

Comment: Why would you want to do that, seems like an unusual requirement?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set page (`http://[servername]/[projectname]/_layouts/Pages/Summary/Default.aspx`) to website welcome page because this page not the part of our current site.

You can set a page to web site welcome page that has the part of our current website. To do this you have to go Site Actions->Site Settings-> Welcome Page (under Look and Feel), set your page as welcome page that has the part of our site. For this you have enabled publishing feature on site.

You can also check:

[Use an application page as the default/welcome page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38419/use-an-application-page-as-the-default-welcome-page)

[Possible to have the default landing page of my Sharepoint Site be an applicaiton page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30419/possible-to-have-the-default-landing-page-of-my-sharepoint-site-be-an-applicaito)